# using regular expression

Tags: php, internal-server-error

I am using

```
$html = file_get_html($url);  
preg_match("/<title>([^>]*)<\/title>/si", $html, $matches);
$title = $matches[1];
```

regular expression to get the title grom a given HTML. It works well on localhost. But when it goes to server it shows `Internal Server Error`.

Please help me if anyone know something about this.

Comment: it is probably not related to your regex but to the url path. can you debug and see if $url looks ok

Comment: it works well for all url's but it Internal Server Error for http://www.youthchairstore.com/product_detail_9735_8924.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think in your live server, curl pear package is not installed. Please check CURL is running or not

Comment: Here i am trying to get the title from external url. http://www.youthchairstore.com/product_detail_9735_8924.aspx is not  on my server. are you sure that this is about curl pear packages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try printing `$html` contents before matching.
   (may i suggest `var_export()` as it is my favourite dumping function)
2. Try `file_get_contents()` instead of that `file_get_html()`
3. Check with your web host if they have `fsockopen()` and related network functionality enabled and available to you, ***many does not.*** (because of DoS concerns)
4. this doesn't look to be really regex related